# Occur error in compile build.py in BlocklyDuino

Tags: javascript, python-2.7

I try to edit the BlocklyDuino.
I download the BlocklyDuino zipped file on the [github](https://github.com/BlocklyDuino/BlocklyDuino), and the [closure-library](http://%20https://developers.google.com/blockly/guides/modify/web/closure)
I used the command `python build.py` to compile it and I got the error

> **ERROR**: Exception in thread Thread-2:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 801, in _*bootstrap_inner
> self.run()
> File "build.py", line 162, in run
> self.gen_core()
> File "build.py", line 190, in gen_core
> self.do_compile(params, target_filename, filenames, "")
> File "build.py", line 256, in do_compile
> json_data = json.loads(json_str)
> File "C:\Python27\lib\json_*init**.py", line 339, in loads
> return _default_decoder.decode(s)
> File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 364, in decode
> obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
> File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
> raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
> ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

I have no idea how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Last week closure compiler stopped accepting HTTP requests.  It is now HTTPS only.  To fix manually, find "HTTPConnection" in build.py and change to "HTTPSConnection".

See this forum post for more context: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/blockly/EDxPuJQ37RI